# How to refine the generic parameter of the returned type?

Tags: kotlin, generics

An example of what I need:

```
interface Interface1

sealed interface Interface2<P0: Interface1>

interface Interface3<P1: Interface1, P2: Interface2<out P1>> {
    // get error: Type parameter cannot have any other bounds if it's bounded by another type parameter
    fun <K: P1, G> getInterface2(): G where G: P2, G: Interface2<K> 
}
```

So in Interface3 I need function that return P2 with concrete descendant of class P1.

I need function getInterface2() to get descendant of Interface2 that have K as P0 parameter.

Answer (score 0):

```
fun <G> getInterface2(): G where G: P2, G: Interface2<out P1>
```

should have the same effect, since any `Interface<K>` extends `Interface2<out P1>`.

Side note: I assume it's an oversimplification, but this signature promises to return a `G` without any way to know what `G` is, so it can't be legitimately implemented.